# Why is ExternalInterface not calling javascript - Flash CC and AS3

Tags: javascript, actionscript-3, flash, externalinterface

So, I've been avoiding posting this question because of the shear amount of prior posts. I've tried several variations of the following code, and to no avail.

I'm using FireFox (latest), Flash Player (latest), AS3, and A couple lines of JavaScript.

Here's my AS3 :

```
import flash.external.*;

// Handling Count For External Refreshing

var count: Number = 0;
var countMax: Number = 3;

function countHandler(): void {
    if (count >= countMax) {
        trace("The count has reached the max " + countMax);
        ExternalInterface.call("refresh");
        count = 0;
    } else {
        trace("The Count is " + count)
        return;
    }
}
```

I've traced the count, the total, all that, so I know that the code is working. It even resets the `count` when it gets to `3`

Here's the javascript :

```
<script language="JavaScript">
    function refresh() {
        window.location.reload();
    }
</script>
```

For giggles/testing, I added a button to the page to test that the above code is working...

```
<input type="button" value="Reload Page" onClick="refresh()">
```

When I press the button, it refreshes the page.

Is there something I'm missing? Why will the working AS3 Not refresh the page by triggering the working javascript?

When I click the button, it refreshes, when the code triggers via ActionScript, I'm unable to press any of the SWF buttons. So it's firing, but not actually refreshing the whole page.

**Update July4th** - Updated AS3 and Java - Still no Luck

Comment: But in your ActionScript code your are calling a `refresh` js function which in reality didn't exist ( at least in your posted code ) ! So your 1st code should be : `ExternalInterface.call("reload");`, try that and tell us what you get.

Comment: @akmozo I'll update the code I have right now. I tried what you said and it didn't work. The button is also using the same `refresh()` method. One Sec...

Comment: Firstly you should know that Java and JavaScript are two different languages ! For your question, I don't know what's your problem exactly, may be you have a security error, try to verify that using flash player debug version which you can get from here : https://www.adobe.com/support/flashplayer/downloads.html ...

Comment: I understand the two are different. I was pretty sure I installed the Debugger version already, but just went ahead and reinstalled it to be sure. I added a crossdomain.xml file to the project directory, as well as set `<param name="allowScriptAccess" value="*" />`

Comment: What options will the debugger afford me in this instance?

Comment: For js communication you don't need a crossdomain.xml file and the `allowscriptaccess` should be `always` or other values but not `*`. For the debug, normally if you have a security ( or any other error ) you will get a message from the flash player. For more details about external interface take a look [here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7cb2.html). If you have always the problem, I will see it tomorrow because it's really late here.

Comment: Sorry man, but I didn't see it yet now but you have to increment your `count` ( like what you did in `addInt()` ) inside the `else` bloc : `else { count++; trace("The Count is " + count); }` otherwise your `if (count >= countMax){}` will never be true.

Comment: Console Output `true
the Count is 0 Before I add
The Count is 1
the Count is 1 Before I add
The Count is 2
the Count is 2 Before I add
The count has reached the max 3
the Count is 0 Before I add
The Count is 1
the Count is 1 Before I add
The Count is 2
the Count is 2 Before I add
The count has reached the max 3
`  ExternalInterface is available `true` it tells me the count before I add `1` to the `count` - Then it traces `the count has reached the max 3` which is right above `ExternalInterface.call("console.log","testing...");` `ExternalInterface.call("refresh();")`

Comment: I'm getting closer. I changed `allowScriptAccess` to `always` Heres my console output in firefox `Try To Refresh
MPInter....1.html (line 13)
testing...
MPInter....1.html
SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list
 

try { __flash__toXML(refresh();()) ; } catch (e) { "<undefined/>"; }

 
Try To Refresh
MPInter....1.html (line 13)
testing...
MPInter....1.html
SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list
 

try { __flash__toXML(refresh();()) ; } catch (e) { "<undefined/>"; }

 
`

Comment: WhoO! It's working!... I'll post the answer in a moment. Thank you @akmozo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Akmozo for the help.

Set `allowScriptAccess` to `always` - NOT `*` Like the adobe tutorial says (bastards). The SWF can't have any hyphens or dashes. I had to set the file name to `My.Test.File.fla` so when I export/build it outputs the following `flashContent`

```
<div id="flashContent">
    <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="My.Test.File.swf" width="1920" height="1080" id="My.Test.File" style="float: none; vertical-align:middle">
        <param name="movie" value="My.Test.File.swf" />
        ...
        <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="always" />
        ...
    </object>
</div>
```

More info on symbols in nomenclature - [Here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/external/ExternalInterface.html)

Here is the ActionScript I used.

```
// Handling Count For External Refreshing
var count: Number = 0; //start count at 0
var countMax: Number = 3; //max whatever you need it to be
var isAvailable: Boolean = ExternalInterface.available; // checking if avail 

trace(isAvailable); 

function countHandler(): void {
    if (count >= countMax) {
        trace("The count has reached the max " + countMax); // Trace in flash 
        ExternalInterface.call("console.log", "testing..."); // Output to Console
        ExternalInterface.call("refresh"); //fire the refresh script
        count = 0; // reset the count
    } else {
        trace("The Count is " + count)
        return;
    }
}
```

Here is the java script. Placed in `<head>` below `<style>`

```
<script language="JavaScript">
        function refresh() {
            console.log("Try To Refresh");
            window.location.reload();
        }
  </script>
```

I had to create a `crossdomain.xml` file to allow access. I've tested the project several times with and without the `crossdomain.xml` and it without it, I get a `security sandbox` error. Not sure why `allowScriptAccess="always"` isn't working.

**Conclusion**
So it appears that setting `allowScriptAccess` to `*` is a bad idea. I got that from one of Adobe's Security Sandbox tutorials (thanks Adobe). Also, passing `"refresh();"` through `ExternalInterface.call` looks for `refresh` arguments which there are none. The `SWf` file name but not use dashes `-` like this..

This... `MyFileName.swf`

Not this... `My-File-Name.swf`

This code is executing as expected. Thank you all for your input and help.